# Find Number in Javascript string and reverse it

Tags: javascript

If we have only one number my script's working great, but the problem is if O have 2 or more numbers in one string.

My target is find all numbers in string, reverse them and place them in their place.

This is my code:

```
function findNum(input) {
    var string = input;
    var regex = /\d+/g;
    var matches = string.match(regex);
    alert("BEfore reverse " + matches);
    var reverseNum = reverseString(matches + "");
    var replace = /,/g;
    var FinalResult = reverseNum.replace(replace, ".");
    alert(FinalResult);
    return FinalResult;
}

function reverseString(str) {
    var splitString = str.split("");
    alert(splitString);
    var reverseArray = splitString.reverse();
    alert(reverseArray);
    var joinArray = reverseArray.join("");
    alert(joinArray);
    return joinArray;
}

function myFunction() {
     var DynamicTemp = "Test test 0.76 and add num .";
     var tmpNum = findNum(DynamicTemp);
            var stringNum = DynamicTemp;

            var regex = /\d+/g;
            var matches = stringNum.match(regex) + "";

            var replace = /,/g;
            var res = matches.replace(replace, ".");

            var result = stringNum.replace(res, tmpNum);
            DynamicTemp = result;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = DynamicTemp;
}
```

Comment: what is the result of a reversed `0.76`?

Comment: result must be 67.0, for one number its working great, but try to insert additional number in this string, and you will see whats a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need support for IE and older versions of browsers not yet supporting arrow functions (suggested in [Me.Name's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40957426/3002280)), you can use the following function which iterates the matches array and replaces the values with their reverse.

```js
function reverseNumbers(string) {
  var regex = /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g;
  var matches = string.match(regex);
  var res = string;
  for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
    res = res.replace(matches[i], matches[i].split("").reverse().join(""))
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}

reverseNumbers("Test test 0.76 and add num 12 .");
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

The resulting string: `Test test 67.0 and add num 21 .`

Comment: BINGO, thnx, just adding loop))))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet that captures all integers (you can tweak it to add support for decimal number)

What we are doing here is that we convert `matches` into a string first by using `join("")`.

**DO NOT USE `+""` TO CONCATENATE THE ARRAY**. See below to the second snippet to see why.

Then to reverse the string, we have to first convert it into a char Array by using `split("")`. `reverse()` reverses the array and `join("")` converts it into a string back.

```js
var test = "123blah456 random text 789";
var matches = test.match(/\d+/g);
var matchesString = matches.join("");
var matchesArray = matchesString.split("");
var matchesArrayReversed = matchesArray.reverse();
var reversed = matchesArrayReversed.join("");
console.log(reversed);
// outputs "987654321"
```

And here's an explanation as to why your program is not working.

```js
var matches = "123asd456fgh789".match(/\d+/g);
console.log("matches = "+matches);
// After you get the matches using the regex, you have an array.
// matches = ["123","456","789"]
//Now see what happens when you use: matches + ""
console.log("matches+\"\" = "+matches+"");
// matches+"" = "123,456,789"
// The commas from the array are added in when you use:  +""
// The better way of doing this is to use: array.join("")
console.log("matches.join(\"\") = "+matches.join(""));
// matches.join("") = "123456789"
```

Comment: thnx for answer and explain ,can you help me to put them back to string on their places, after reverse.

Comment: @Aleksey The original string with the numbers in their places is stored inside the `test` variable. Also, if this answer has helped your problem, you can "Accept Answer" so that others will know that this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace regex matches, you can also use [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and specify the specific replacement to take place (reversal).

```js
const reverseNumbers = str => str.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g, m => m.split('').reverse().join(''));
console.log(reverseNumbers( "Test test 0.76 and add 123."));
```

The regex is changed to `\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g` to take `.` into account if it is followed by more digits. (other variations possible depending on your need). The 2nd argument in `replace`, is the function which returns the replacement. In this case a reversal of the found match.